# Phoenix frameworks and validating embeds

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Given the following code works fine:

```
image_1 = %Image{naturalHeight: "100", naturalWidth: 100}

diffbot_objects = [
  %DiffbotObject{
    availability: true,
    images: [
      image_1
    ]
  }
]

changeset = Ecto.Changeset.change(product)
changeset = Ecto.Changeset.put_embed(changeset, :diffbot_objects, diffbot_objects)
```

How can I ensure that fields are validated on the Image model? I can generate a changeset using the the changeset method on the Image model (see below) but I'm unable to insert data using a nested changeset, it has to be e struct it seems.

My image model:

```
defmodule Shopshare.Product.DiffbotObject.Image do
  use Shopshare.Web, :model

  embedded_schema do
    field :naturalHeight, :integer
    field :naturalWidth, :integer
  end

  @required_fields ~w(naturalHeight, naturalWidth)
  @optional_fields ~w()

  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw that you are using `put_embed` but I don't see the schema from product. I don't know if this is the real problem. But I tried some code that works.

I create a new app with Blog and Post model. I used the generate models:

```
mix phoenix.gen.model Blog blogs name:string
mix phoenix.gen.model Post posts title:string body:text blog_id:references:blogs
```

I'm using a simple validation for required fields. Let's take a deeper look into Blog model:

```
    defmodule MyApp.Blog do
      use MyApp.Web, :model

      schema "blogs" do
        field :name, :string
        has_many :posts, MyApp.Post

        timestamps
      end

      @required_fields ~w(name)
      @optional_fields ~w()

      def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
        model
        |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
      end
    end
```

I create manually the `has_many` association with posts (it isn't created with my generate model). Now, we have the Post model:

```
    defmodule MyApp.Post do
      use MyApp.Web, :model

      schema "posts" do
        field :title, :string
        field :body, :string
        belongs_to :blog, MyApp.Blog

        timestamps
      end

      @required_fields ~w(title body)
      @optional_fields ~w()

      def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
        model
        |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
      end
    end
```

Now, we can play in the IEx (`iex -S mix`):

```
    iex(1)> blog_changeset = MyApp.Blog.changeset(%MyApp.Blog{}, %{name: "blog name"})
    %Ecto.Changeset{...}

    iex(2)> blog_changeset.valid?
    true

    iex(3)> invalid_post_changeset = MyApp.Post.changeset(%MyApp.Post{}, %{})
    %Ecto.Changeset{...}

    iex(4)> blog_changeset = Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(blog_changeset, :posts, [invalid_post_changeset])
    %Ecto.Changeset{action: nil,
    changes: %{name: "blog name",
      posts: [%Ecto.Changeset{action: :insert,
        changes: ..., constraints: [],
        errors: [title: "can't be blank", body: "can't be blank"], filters: %{},
        ...]}, ...,
    model: %MyApp.Blog{...}, optional: [], opts: [], params: %{"name" => "blog name"},
    prepare: [], repo: nil, required: [:name],
    types: %{...},
    valid?: false, validations: []}

    iex(5)> blog_changeset.valid?
    false
```

I suppressed some output to focus in the the errors. `Changeset` works like a tree. So, you can have the parent changeset and the children. The difference from your code is that I'm using the `put_assoc` (https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#put_assoc/4) (maybe the relation too, but I didn't see your schema).

The behaviour expected from `put_assoc`:

> If the association has no changes, it will be skipped. If the association is invalid, the changeset will be marked as invalid. If the given value is not an association, it will raise.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: This is a terrific answer Erich, thanks for writing it up. I wound up implementing things in their own table in the end so I can't test your answer, but appreciate it being typed up liked this.